# Show that $\Omega$ and $\emptyset$ are independent of any event.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Show that $\Omega$ and $\emptyset$ are independent of any event.

Definition. Two events $A$ and $B$ are independent if and only if $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$

I suppose I should make a formal argument.

$P(\Omega)=1$, $P(A\cap \Omega)=P(A)=P(A)\cdot 1=P(A)P(\Omega)$, for all events $A$

$P(\emptyset)=0$, $P(A \cap \emptyset )=P(\emptyset)=0=0\cdot P(A)=P(\emptyset)P(A)$, for all events $A$.

Comment: Everything is correct, but what is question?

Comment: If what I did is right?

Comment: @zkutch  It looks like she wanted confirmation, which you supplied.

Comment: Yes, @Kitty M. You did right. Thanks for question.

Answer (score 1):

As other commenters have observed, you correctly supplied the argument for independence.

Let me add some remarks of informal nature. Probability 1 actually means certainty and so should have no bearing on any other events happening. Take a certain event in life,  " Kumar is going to die ".
Let $A$ be an event that " Mrs Kumar will become the CEO of Google", or "There will be heavy  snow on Kumar's next birthday".  As the certain event is going to happen regardless of the other two events we can see their independence.

Same way one can see probability 0 events to be independent of any other event.  Take the  event "USA will discontinue its Nuclear Arsenal". It is an impossible event and it is going to be independent of the events like "Saudi Arabia reduces price of Crude Oil by 15%", or "Tomorrow I am going to skip my breakfast".

Independence of two events means  lack of impact for happening of an event on another.